# How to select all attributes that are not in relation to the other attribute

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL right now and I have some difficulties with a query want to write.

I have a table with R(A,B,C) and I want to select A,B where all B are not in relation with A

For example:

Table R

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | x |
| 2 | yellow | y |
| 3 | green | z |

And I want:

Table X

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | yellow |
| 1 | green |
| 2 | red |
| 2 | green |
| 3 | yellow |
| 3 | green |

To be honest, I have no clue how to tackle this problem. Any hint or tip would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want a *Cartesian product* of columns A and B.

Comment: uh, good point! i did not think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate all rows and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select a.a, b.b
from (select distinct a from r) a cross join
     (select distinct b from r) b left join
     r
     on r.a = a.a and r.b = b.b
where r.a is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely forgot about cross join!